# In Buck, how do I expand a genrule output directory?

Tags: c++, buck

I have a `genrule` that outputs a directory containing C++ headers. I also have a `cxx_library` which uses the output of the `genrule`. The `headers` field of the `cxx_library` looks like this:

```
  ...
  headers = [
    ':my-headers',
  ],
  ...
```

The problem is that my C++ source files include the headers like this:

```
#include "my_header.h"
```

But Buck prepares the staging area like this:

```
my-cxx-library#default,private-headers/out
```

Where `out` is an alias to the folder containing my generated headers.

So in order to use the headers, I would have to include them like this:

```
#include "out/my_header.h"
```

The library is not my own, so I would not like to change the source-code. Instead, I would like to use something like a `subdir_glob` to include everything inside `:my-headers/out`.

I tried this:

```
  ...
  headers = subdir_glob([
    (':my-headers/out', '**/*.h'),
  ]),
  ...
```

However, it seems that when done this way, the string `:my-headers` does not get resolved to the output path of `:my-headers`.

Is there a function in [buck](/questions/tagged/buck) that can expand a rule to its output path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [isn't trivially possible today](https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/518), but there is a workaround you can use:

```
genrule(
  name = 'headers',
  cmd = 'generate_headers.py --outdir=$OUT'
  out = 'headers-dir',
)
genrule(
  name = 'generated_header_A.h',
  cmd = 'cp $(location :headers)/genereated_header_A.h $OUT',
  out = 'generated_header_A.h',
)
```

Then, in your `cxx_library`, you just need to declare your `headers` by referencing the location:

```
  headers = {
    'some_namespace/header_A.h': ':generated_header_A.h',
  },
```

The above code assumes all of this is in the same [build file](https://buckbuild.com/concept/build_file.html), but if it isn't, you just need to use a fully-qualified [build target](https://buckbuild.com/concept/build_target.html) instead.

Comment: Saved my day even in 2023